# why foreach over writing the value instead of return all values

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage

following is an array that needed to be store on local storage when the dom is created.

```
  this.headers.push( 
   {
      text: "Name",
      align: "center",
      sortable: true,
      value: "name",
      align: "start",
    },
    {
      text: "Company",
      align: "center",
      sortable: true,
      value: "company",
      align: "start",
    },
    {
      text: "Phone",
      align: "center",
      sortable: true,
      value: "phone",
      align: "start",
    },
   )]
```

the value of each object needed to be store on localstorage under the key name `el_columns`. so I have tried as follows.

```
   this.headersList.forEach((element) => {
      localStorage.setItem(
        "el_columns",
        JSON.stringify(element.value)
      );
    });
```

the above code works fine but is stores only one value which is the last object value `phone`. the output i expect is like follows `['name', 'company', 'phone']`

Comment: It is not storing one value, but over writing previous stored value.

Comment: so how may i stop over writing and store all the values

Comment: Use `map` to get an array of `value`s. No need for forEach: `JSON.stringify(this.headers.map(h => h.value))`

Comment: how are you getting local storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 this.headersList.forEach((element) => {
      localStorage.setItem(
        "el_columns_"+element.text,
        JSON.stringify(element.value)
      );
    });
```

Comment: NOT SOLVED. it creates seperate key values as for each object.

Comment: Try localStorage.setItem("el_columns_", JSON.stringify(this.headers));

Comment: ` let result = obj.map((col) => col.value);` this is the working code i found